# Nothing has worked to code PHP in Visual Studio Code via Windows 10

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am taking a Udemy class for WordPress. I can create a function just fine. However, when I started using the variables and array it will not work. I get a message saying there is no "php.validate.executablePath" and "php.executablePath" via settings.json.

So I downloaded the zip file of PHP 7.3 (7.3.17) VC15 x64 Non Thread Safe and extracted it to C:\php7.3. I then added the path to the settings.json: "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\php7.3\php.exe", "php.executablePath": "C:\php7.3\php.exe"

I then restarted my VSC and nothing happened. I even restarted my computer. The notification never popped up again but I still cannot run PHP. In replace of the \, I used one \, then one /, then two / but it did not change anything. I looked this issue up - found others who had the same issue - and have not found anything that has worked for me so far.

I also tried downloading the xampp but there was an issue at port 443. That's when I downloaded the PHP file directly and uninstalled xampp.

EDIT: Do I have to have something like xampp or wamp to execute the PHP? If so, I would just need to figure out how to fix that error.

Here is a screenshot of the code I used: http://prntscr.com/sahb1f

Here is a screenshot of the settings.json: http://prntscr.com/sahbk0

I am on Windows 10 x64. A tool extension for VSC costs money, which I do not want to spend.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `echo` in front of the `$names[0]` array element access.

change your line to this `<p>Hi, my name is <?php echo $names[0]; ?></p>` and it should work however your error to do with executablePath might be because of something else.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I overlooked that. I was so hung up on the PHP error and fixing it that I overlooked a very simple mistake. So much wasted time I'm pissed. Thank you for your help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No worries, it happens to all of us as we are learning. This is what helps us learn :) Keep up the learning.